# Accidentally rebooted OnePlus 6 with no OS installed, how to get back to TWRP?

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, twrp, lineageos, oneplus-6

In the process of installing LineageOS on my OnePlus 6 A6003, I accidentally pressed "reboot to system" when there was no OS installed. How can I get back to TWRP? I've tried holding Power+Vol Down but it just boots with the oneplus logo then unlocked bootloader warning then black screen with the status LED on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97663/discussion-between-retnikt-and-irfan-latif).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with [this tool](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-6/how-to/rom-stock-fastboot-roms-oneplus-6-t3796665).

Instructions:

> Download the zip;
>   Unpack the zip in a folder;
>   Reboot the OnePlus 6 in fastboot mode (Power and volume-);
>   Connect the OnePlus 6 to PC;
>   Run flash-all.bat flasher you need;
>   Wait until the process end;
>   The phone will automatically reboot.

Downloads: https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=271877

Comment: Hello. Would you please follow our [answer] guide to write a good, self-contained answer. As the answer currently is, it would lose its usefulness if the link expires. Links are supposed to be mentioned to download some item or suggest a reading material.

Comment: @Firelord but the answer will be useless anyway if the link goes down because the tool itself will be inaccessible...?

Comment: the tool might be available on some mirror or some other forum/website but the tutorial might not be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to press **vol-up + power** and then **briefly (1-2 secs) let go** of the power button (don't let go of the vol-up button yet!) and hold it down again until you see the TWRP splash screen.

Comment: When I do this I just get back to fastboot mode